# Logistic mixed model

Tags: logistic, estimation, likelihood, mixed-model

In the logistic mixed model ${\rm logit}(P(Y_i=1))= α + βX_i + u_i + ε_i , i=1,...,m$, when we know $u_i\sim \mathcal N(0,σu^2)$, and $ε_i\sim\mathcal N(0,σi^2)$,
and if we know $σi^2$ in each area $i$:

1. How do we use $σi^2$ in estimation of parameters (likelihood formula)?
2. How can we estimate the $σu^2$?